# How run spring boot jar with class path resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, command-line

I have a spring boot application. It works perfectly if I run it from Eclipse. But if I run the same from command prompt, I am getting the following error

**ERROR**

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory]: Factory method 'kafkaProducerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Resource 'class path resource [kafka/somejksfile.jks]' must be on a file system\r\n\tat

I extracted the .jar file and I was able to see the Kafka related .jks file inside
projectName\BOOT-INF\classes

For some reason it is not picking all the files which are inside src/main/resources. How to refer that location when running the .jar from command prompt. I tried the following with no luck

java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=dev -Dspring.config.location=file:\\C:\my-files\poc\projectName\src\main\resources\ api-account-info.jar

Note: I cannot make any code changes

Comment: It must be a file on the filesystem not a packaged resource inside a jar, that is what the error is telling you as well. So you cannot (apparently) pack this file in a jar and have it run. It works in eclipse because than it is a physical file on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by the following.

1. Downloaded Spring Boot CLI and extracted it. (https://repo.spring.io/release/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-cli/2.6.2/spring-boot-cli-2.6.2-bin.zip)
2. Set environment variable

Variable: SPRING_HOME
Value: C:\my-files\Installations\spring-boot-cli-2.6.2-bin\spring-2.6.2

Variable: Path
Value: %SPRING_HOME%\bin

3. From command prompt run the following commands

SET SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=dev
mvn spring-boot:run

This will build and start the application.